# Чтение логов в Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеется проект RoR на Windows. Есть задача читать и анализировать логи проекта. 
Суть вопроса - какой инструментарий лучше всего использовать? В идеале - чтение событий через веб. Но возможно подключение и по ssh и по rdp.
Я знаю про  rsyslog, logstash, fluent. Но интересует пример реального использования подобных инструментов, связка с другим инструментарием и чему отдать предпочтение.
Ну и это всё на Windows

Comment: Запись логов через Filebeat прямо в ElasticSearch и осмотр результатов через Kibana в браузере -- вполне рабочий вариант.

Comment: А чем не подходит консольный текстовый редактор, раз есть доступ по ssh?